# Sliders not Removing Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, material-ui

Here is all the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/users").then((response) =>
      response.json().then((data) => {
        this.setState({ users: data.users });
      })
    );
  }
  removeSlider(user) {
    const users = [...this.state.users];
    users.splice(users.indexOf(user), 1);
    this.setState({ users: users });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.users.map((user) => (
          <div className="slider" id="di">
            <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
              <button className="btn" onClick={() => this.removeSlider(user)}>
                {user.first_name[0].toUpperCase() + user.first_name.slice(1)}
              </button>
            </Typography>
            <Slider
              orientation="vertical"
              defaultValue={[0, 50]}
              aria-labelledby="vertical-slider"
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The users come from another server. The in the typography each user has a button that essentially removes them from the list of users (handled by the removeSlider handler).
The problem here is that when I do this the slider that correspondes with the end of the list gets removed instead of the one I want to delete.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So in the pictures I go to delete Jordan, but Imagine's slider gets removed. Jordan was in fact removed from the array of users though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A warning in your console should be telling you what the problem is. You need to specify a meaningful key in `<div className="slider" id="di">` (e.g. `<div className="slider" id="di" key={user.id}>`).

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user is removed, because of a state change, React re-renders the page, and inside the `map` React will draw 5 sliders, which it will associate with the first 5 sliders as you haven't added [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to them.

So a first step would be to add keys to the sliders in map, then the re-rendering should keep and re-use the correct old objects and not re-draw or mis-align them.

Also, you might want to store the sliders' values in the state, making them "controlled components" (set their `value` from state, and handle their `change` events to update the state) so that they don't lose their info between renders.

Comment: It is not correct that React will draw 5 new sliders. Since no key (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) is being specified in `<div className="slider" id="di">` (the root element within the array iteration), the elements will be identified by index within React, so React will see the "last" one as having been removed and others are just being re-rendered with a change to the user's name.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks @RyanCogswell, that is what I meant - the sliders are not being recognised by their key, so just adding a key might fix the problem. I've added in some clarification and more info on keys.